# RGB-backlight keyboard interactive context-sensitive integration with Linux environment

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I would like for example when editing in VI, that my RGB keyboard would highlight shortcut keys in different colors, or when I press CTRL in gnome then pgup, pgdown, up, down, would be highlighted in red color, alt and shift green color, etc. The color of keys would depend on the current context. Is there any such project going on? Is it even possible to accomplish? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, maybe not easy. It is a bit of vendor dependent since you need to send the proper signals to the keyboard hardware. There is the [openrgb](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB) prokect that tries to accomplish it to many devices and explains how this effect can be achieved.